# viewDidAppear issues in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I just started coding with iOS 13 and am having issues with view controller functions. Previous to iOS 13 I had a view controller presented using this function

```
func presentDetail(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController){

        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.22
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
        self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

        present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

And when dismissed, viewDidAppear in the root view controller would trigger. Now in iOS 13 it seems like the VC is built on top of the root VC, and when dismissed it does NOT trigger viewDidAppear in the root VC. Is there a different function I have to use or do I have to completely change my approach? root VC viewDidAppear currently triggers when viewDidLoad and when user switches to it from tab bar, any advice would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default presentation style, which is the card style, will not trigger `viewDidAppear` when you dismiss the view controller.

You'll most likely have to switch to a different `modalPresentationStyle` that will trigger it. One of the presentation style's that does trigger it for example is `.fullScreen`

So for example, for `viewControllerToPresent` you'd want to set it's presentation style to

`viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

before you present it

Comment: Do you know any functions that would execute when card style VC is dismissed? I kind of like it

Comment: Not that I know of. You'll most likely have to pass a closure to `viewControllerToPresent` and when you dismiss it, in the completion closure just call it