# UIViewController viewDidAppear no longer called on iOS13 devices

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

After updating to Xcode 11, an existing project's UIViewControllers no longer call viewDidAppear.

To confirm this is related to iOS13, I selected an emulator running iOS12 and the issue went away.

Comment: Consider that a presented controller as *sheet* doesn’t cause the presenting controller to call `viewWillAppear/Disappear` in iOS 13.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [viewDidAppear issues in iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349560/viewdidappear-issues-in-ios-13)